# Magento 1.7.0.2 Catalog -> google site-map giving 404 page

Tags: magento-1.7

My store in magento ver 1.7.0.2 and when i clicked on catalog -> google site page it just gives me 404 page .

I can't find what happen. i find that change file permission but which folder not specified any one can help me .

Comment: What is "google site page"?

Comment: I can't understand please exmplain brief what you said ...

Comment: Any one have idea i can't get any solution on google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multi-store website and you deleted many of store than table **sitemap** and  **cms_page_store** both table have relation with **core_store** table.

But due to some reason your store information not deleted in both table.

You need to delete all store entry which not exit in **core_store** table.

For deleting site map entry "DELETE FROM sitemap
WHERE store_id NOT IN (SELECT store_id FROM core_store)"

Its getting proved here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414761/magento-cms-pages-index-page-not-open-in-admin-panel